# Product Attributes could not be reindexed

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, index

I am recieving this error while trying to reindex "Product Attributes". Can anyone suggest, what might be the issue and possible solution

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2828-148-1-471' for key 'PRIMARY'' in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array) #5 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO`ca...', Array) #6 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1998): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234

Comment: Did you import the database via phpmyadmin?

Comment: No, i am just adding the products programatically @Flyinglama

Answer (score 15):

**How to interpret the error message**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2828-148-1-471' 
for key 'PRIMARY
```

In the case of the product attribute indexer, this means there's a constraint error while saving a record to the `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` table.

`2828-148-1-471` refers to:

- product entity id: 2828
- attribute id: 148
- store id: 1
- value: 471

**Possible origin of the problem**

I'm assuming that the attribute that's causing problems is of type multiselect. A value which is linked multiple times to a product, will cause this type of error.

You can check this by executing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` 
where entity_id = 2828 and attribute_id = 148 and store_id = 1;
```

I'm guessing that the id 471 will be listed multiple times in the column `value`. Every id should only be listed once in that column.

Are you using an importer to add product data to Magento?

Comment: Yes, it's inchoo's simple product programatic import

Comment: Any solution on this, yes it is a multi select

Answer (score 7):

Below solution worked for me and may help others :

2828-148-1-471 refers to:

product entity id: 2828
attribute id: 148
store id: 1
value: 471

Just open product with id 2828 and save it and reindex again.

that may solve your problem

Comment: What solution for bulk update?

Answer (score 3):

I got it, it was an issue with the multi select dropdown attributes, In my script, sometimes same attribute was being added multiple times which was causing error, posting this answer for someone if need help in future